# Erlang spawn returns undef for some reason

Tags: erlang

I am getting a response from Erlang when running with 100 sensors, all process return some version of

Error in process <0.124.0> with exit value:
{undef,[{main,watcher_start,[10,0],[]}]}

I am unsure as to what I am doing wrong.

Here is main.erl

```
-module(main).
-import(watcher,[watcher_start/2]).
-import(sensor, [sensor_run/2]).
-compile(export_all).

%given
start() ->
    {ok, [ N ]} = io:fread("enter number of sensors> ", "~d"), 
    if N =< 1 ->
        io:fwrite("setup: range must be at least 2~n", []); 
    true ->
        Num_watchers = 1 + (N div 10),
        setup_loop(N, Num_watchers) 
    end.

setup_loop(SenN, Watcher_count) ->
    setup_loop(SenN, Watcher_count, 0).

setup_loop(SenN, Watcher_count, SID) when SenN =< 10 ->
    spawn(?MODULE, watcher_start, [SenN, SID]);

setup_loop(SenN, Watcher_count, SID) ->
    spawn(?MODULE, watcher_start, [10, SID]),
    setup_loop(SenN - 10, Watcher_count - 1, SID + 10).
```

and watcher.erl

```
-module(watcher).
-import(sensor, [sensor_run/2]).
-compile(export_all).

watcher_start(SenN, SID) ->
    %report start and run the watcher. Generate the list with number of sensors
    TheSensorList = gen_list(SenN, SID, []),

    io:fwrite("The watcher service is started ~w~n", [TheSensorList]),
    watcher_run(TheSensorList).

watcher_run(SensorList) ->
    receive
        %recieve a measurement, print it out and mainatain the same list as it has not changed
        {From, Measurement} ->
            io:fwrite("Sensor ~p gave a Measurement of ~p~n", [From, Measurement]),
            UpdatedSensorList = SensorList;
        %process with PID is down, a sesnor crashed
        {'DOWN', _, process, PID, Reason} ->
            %Find the sensor ID (SID) of the process that is down
            {_, SID} = lists:keyfind(PID, 1, SensorList),
            %report the failure that has been deteced
            io:fwrite("Sensor ~p has crashed with error ~p i will attempt to restart it~n", [SID, Reason]),
            %restart the sensor, the new process will have a new PID & report it
            {UpdatedPID, _} = spawn_monitor(sensor, sensor_run, [self(), SID]),
            %Now we canm actually updatethe list with a new value
            UpdatedSensorList = lists:keyreplace(SID, 2, SensorList, {UpdatedPID, SID}),
            io:fwrite("The sensor ~p was restarted with PID ~p", [SID, UpdatedPID])
    end,
    watcher_run(UpdatedSensorList).

gen_list(SenN, SID, TheList) ->
    %create the monitor and continue unil all the SenN number of monitors have been created
    {PID, _} = spawn_monitor(sensor, sensor_run, [self(), SID]),
    %continue and add the tuple of the new monitor to the list
    gen_list(SenN - 1, SID +1, TheList++[{PID, SID}]);

%Base case when we are out of SenN monitors
gen_list(0, _, TheList) ->
    TheList.
```

what am I doing wrong? I have watcher_run/2 imported and should be sending 2 parameters to it.

Comment: In addition to @7Stud answer, I would recommend to avoid import: import is not necessary and is just a short cut in writing, and also to avoid avoid compile(export_all) and prefer an explicit export list which make clear the interface of the module: export is necessary and defines the function that are accessible from other modules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the definition of [import](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/modules.html):

> **-import(Module,Functions).**
>
> Imported functions. Can be called the same way as local functions,
>   that is, without any module prefix.
>
> Module, an atom, specifies which module to import functions from.
>   Functions is a list similar as for export.

This line:

```
spawn(?MODULE, watcher_start, [SenN, SID]);
```

appears in the module `main`, so the macro `?MODULE` is replaced by `main`.  As a result, you are asking erlang to spawn a process that executes `main:watcher_start(SenN, SID)`.  However, `watcher_start/2` is not defined in the `main` module--it's defined in the `watcher` module.  In other words, when you import a function into a module it does not mean that you can treat that function as part of the module.

The fix is to either call:

```
spawn(watcher, watcher_start, [SenN, SID]);
```

or because you are importing `watcher_start/2` you can omit the module name and call:

```
   spawn(
         fun() -> watcher_start(SenN, SID) end
   ).
```

You have the same issue in this line:

```
spawn(?MODULE, watcher_start, [10, SID]),
```

Importing a module may save some typing but it comes at the expense of code clarity.  You might consider never using import in your code.